# Creating a datetime column from timstamp and string type columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this in which `hours` are of type `str` and `date` is of type `timestamp`:

```
hours           date
00:18:00        2020-07-15 
23:30:00        2020-07-15  
23:20:00        2020-07-15  
23:20:00        2020-07-15  
23:20:00        2020-07-15
```

I would like to transform `date` column to follow this format:

```
2020-07-15 00:18:00 #and have timestamp format
```

What I tried:

```
df['date'] = (str(df['date'])+df['hours']).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

But I get:

> ValueError: time data 2020071500:18:00 doesn't match format specified

Comment: try this, ```pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['hours'], format="%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a hint from @Sushanth's comment and modified it. Thanks.

```
df['date_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['hours'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df
    hours   date    date_hour
0   00:18:00    2020-07-15  2020-07-15 00:18:00
1   23:30:00    2020-07-15  2020-07-15 23:30:00
2   23:20:00    2020-07-15  2020-07-15 23:20:00
3   23:20:00    2020-07-15  2020-07-15 23:20:00
4   23:20:00    2020-07-15  2020-07-15 23:20:00
```